# Hibernate validator issues tracking

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

The Hibernate validator issues tracker appears to indicate that a particular [issue](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HV-46) I am facing is fixed - but I am still suffering from this issue and we're on the latest version (4.0.2).

The change history and summary seem to indicate this was fixed in 3.2.0 but then on the other hand the issue status is listed as "open"..

Can anyone clarify?

This is the Maven entry we're using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the issue says *Status: Open* then it hasn't been fixed. The *Fix Version* field suggests it had been scheduled for 3.2.0, but clearly that didn't happen (in fact it also says *Unassigned*).